# How to print a recordset using Smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I need to show the result of a query(mysql), how can I loop the recordset without assign the values to an array?
Now I do:

```
while($row = $this->mysql->fetch($rs)){
  val[] = $row
}
$this->smarty->assign('val', val);
```

then (in the template.tpl)

```
{section name=nr loop=$val}
{$val[nr].cod}<br />
{sectionelse}
<h1>No record</h1>
{/section}
```

How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Smarty's foreach, although it doesn't make it any shorter:

```
{if $val}
    {foreach from=$val item=nr}
        {$nr.cod}<br />
    {/foreach}
{else}
    <h1>No record</h1>
{/if}
```

Comment: No, I asked how can show the "recordset" (my recordset) as you can see I save the rows in an array, do i need to do that? can i not print the recordset directly?

Comment: @Dail you cannot print the recordset without saving it to an array unless you embed PHP code in the Smarty template. That is an undesirable practice.  Storing it to an array first is the proper way to handle it.

Comment: If you were using PDO (or any DB abstraction that gives you an iteratable result set), you can assign the result-set and have smarty iterate it for you. (this won't work with the old mysql_query() stuff)

Answer (score 0):

maybe [{html_table}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.table.tpl) can help. Otherwise you're free to iterate your rows and cols however you like:

```
{foreach $val as $row}
  {if $row@first}
    <table>
    <tbody>
  {/if}
  {foreach $row as $cell}
      {if $cell@first}
        <tr>
      {/if}

      <td>{$cell|escape:"html}</td>

      {if $cell@last}
        </tr>
      {/if}
  {foreach}
  {if $row@last}
    </tbody>
    </table>
  {/if}
{foreachelse}
  <p>No Data</p>
{/foreach}
```

(Smarty3 syntax of [{foreach}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl))

You can also output the cells' keys:

```
{foreach $val as $row}
  {if $row@first}
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    {foreach $row as $cell}
      <th>{$cell@key|escape:"html}</th>
    {/foreach}
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  {/if}
  {foreach $row as $cell}
      {if $cell@first}
        <tr>
      {/if}

      <td>{$cell|escape:"html}</td>

      {if $cell@last}
        </tr>
      {/if}
  {foreach}
  {if $row@last}
    </tbody>
    </table>
  {/if}
{foreachelse}
  <p>No Data</p>
{/foreach}
```